# How to format a date from ps -p {PID} -o etime= into PHP's datetime?

Tags: php, date, datetime, unix, php-7.1

I am currently running on a server a python script that lists all the biggest sequences I can find. And for the presentation, I want to specify since how long is the script running.

For the moment, I am using the function `shell_exec('ps -p 1696 -o etime=')` to fetch the time elapsed since I started the process.
It is fine for 24h, after this, I am having a weird syntax with `dd-hh:mm:ss`

I don't find any solution from all the date related functions from php7.1 to parse this value yet, do you have any idea of what should I do to get the time "readable". Would Regex be the thing to do here ?

I mean there that I would like the php file to echo something like "Script Running since 2 days, 16 hours 35 minutes and 14 seconds"

This is my php file :

```
<?php
$time = shell_exec('ps -p 1696 -o etime='); 
// Where 1696 is the PID of the python script
echo "Collatz.py running since :" . $time; 
echo '<pre>'.file_get_contents('/var/www/html/logs.txt').'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to match the time string that it produced by `ps`, group them into matching groups and then use them to build your string.

```php
$time = shell_exec('ps -p 3646 -o etime=');

preg_match("/^(((\\d*)-)?(\\d*):)?(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})$/", $time, $matches);

$days = $matches[3];
$hours = $matches[4];
$minutes = $matches[5];
$seconds = $matches[6];

$time_string = "";
$time_string .= strlen($days) > 0 ? $days . " days, " : "";
$time_string .= strlen($hours) > 0 ? $hours . " hours " : "";
$time_string .= strlen($minutes) > 0 ? $minutes . " minutes and " : "";
$time_string .= $seconds . " seconds";

echo "Running since: " . $time_string;
```

Comment: I used my own regex since yours wasn't really adpated : `/([0-9]+-)?((?>[0-9]{2}))?\:([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})$/`, but thanks for leading me on the regex path, I really didn't know what was the best solution